# Navigation Editor not available in Intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am trying to setup a android development environment in Intellij on OSX 10.10 and when I go to tools/android/ I don't see the navigation editor. It should be in the top as the first option to choose. I have googled and searched everywhere but I can't find a solution to make it show. Is there any guru who can point me out to the right direction? :)

[image]

Comment: What if you press the OSX equivalent of `ctrl+shift+A` (find action shortkey), and type `navigation editor`?

Comment: I can see the show navigation editor option but when I click on it nothing happens